# How to prove that $\sum_{i=1}^n\|x_i\|_2^4\leq d\|\sum_{i=1}^nx_ix_i^T\|_2\max_{i=1}^n\|x_i\|_2^2$ for any $x_i\in R^d$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

In the question, $\|\cdot\|_2$ means $l_2$ norm for vectors OR spectral norm for matrices. Thanks in advance.

The question is reformulated from page 7 of paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.00898v2.pdf.

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced that this holds. For $n=1$, this means $\lVert x\rVert^2\leq d \lVert x x^T\rVert\lVert x\rVert^2$. Using $\lVert xx^T\rVert=\lVert x\rVert^2$ yields $1\leq d\lVert x\rVert^2$ for arbitrary $x\in R^d\setminus\{0\}$. This is not true, is it?

Comment: I am very sorry. I have changed  $\sum_{i=1}^n\|x_i\|_2^2$ to $\sum_{i=1}^n\|x_i\|_2^4$. Thanks.

Comment: @Piwi please help me.

Comment: I'm sorry, it was nighttime here. I posted my idea for this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't feel very confident here, but since nobody answered, I'll give it a try. Please check carefully.

Note that since $\sum_{i=1}^n \lVert x_i\rVert^4\leq\max_{i=1}^n\lVert x_i\rVert^2\sum_{i=1}^n\lVert x_i\rVert^2$, it would be enough to show

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\lVert x_i\rVert^2\leq d\left\lVert\sum_{i=1}^n x_i x_i^T\right\rVert.$$

Look at the matrix on the right hand side (which is the sum of the dyadic products $x_ix_i^T$) and observe that this is a symmetric matrix looking like this:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_ix_i^T=\begin{pmatrix}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_{i1})^2 & \sum_{i=1}^nx_{i1}x_{i2} & \sum_{i=1}^nx_{i1}x_{i3} & \cdots\\\sum_{i=1}^nx_{i1}x_{i2} & \sum_{i=1}^nx_{i2}^2 & \sum_{i=1}^nx_{i2}x_{i3} & \cdots\\\vdots & & \ddots\hspace{3em} & \vdots \end{pmatrix}$$

This symmetric matrix is positive semi-definite as sum of the positive semi-definite matrices $x_ix_i^T$. So all eigenvalues $\lambda_k$ are non-negative and the spectral norm of this matrix equals the largest eigenvalue $\lambda_\max$, i.e. $\lVert \sum_{i=1}^n x_ix_i^T\rVert=\lambda_\max$. Now estimate

$$d\left\lVert \sum_{i=1}^n x_ix_i^T\right\rVert=d~\lambda_\max\geq \sum_{k=1}^d \lambda_k\overset{(*)}{=}\mathrm{Tr}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_ix_i^T\right)=\sum_{k=1}^d\sum_{i=1}^n x_{ik}^2=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^dx_{ik}^2=\sum_{i=1}^n\lVert x_i\rVert^2$$

where we used that all eigenvalues are non-negative and that our matrix is symmetric in equality $(*)$.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is correct!